# Total size of all file types in a folder

Tags: windows, file, filesize

Is there any way/too in window7 to see the total size of files of particular type ? For example if I have directory which has 5 files. 2 files are Jpg, 1 is log file and 2 are docx file. In such case, it should report something like below

jpg -           2 files-   Total size   -10 MB
log file -      1 file-    Total size   -5KM
document file - 2 file -   Total        -45 MB

-Rajesh

Comment: Not without a custom program or if you sort by file-type and select only the type you want co add up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a way to do this in linux (e.g. some form of ls or grep)?  If there is, it is probably supported by [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

In other words, you could install cygwin and then run something like the 'find' command shown here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/558979/how-to-display-disk-usage-by-file-type.

Also, if you put the cygwin executable directory in your PATH environment you can run all of the cywin commands from a windows command prompt.

And if you just want a good way to see where all of your disk space is being used there are a number of [good tools for that](https://www.howtogeek.com/113012/10-best-free-tools-to-analyze-hard-drive-space-on-your-windows-pc/).  I personally like [spacesniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/).

Answer (score 0):

You can start a command window and use dir.

ex:

```
dir *.txt
```